# How to print out puzzle in HTML

Tags: java, html

```
String html="<div><h1>This is the HTML for word puzzle</hi></div>";

 File fileh=new File("puzzle.html");

 BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileh));
 for(int i=0; i<dataF.length; i++) {
 for(int j=0; j<dataF[i].length; j++) {
bw.print(dataF[i][j]);
}
bw.println(" ");
}
 bw.close();
```

This should print out something like a 50*50 puzzle, but I'm not sure how the print and println work in HTML, also can someone give me an idea how to bold specific letters in HTML. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you're just looking for an HTML tutorial, there are many of those available via Google.  Have you tried something that isn't working?  Is there a specific error you need help with?

Comment: I tried but it only printed out unorganized stuff, so I hope someone can tell me how print and println work for HTML

Comment: It certainly wasn't "random", unless there's something else *very* wrong with your system.  What *was* the output?  What did you *expect* it to be?  We can help you with a problem if you can explain the problem.  `print` and `println` don't have anything to do with HTML.  Those are methods in Java.

Comment: I know it have to use 'write',  It should print out a 50*50 puzzle fill with letters(50*50 2D array), but when I check it only printed out 25 rows and 75 columns.

Comment: Then it would seem that `dataF` doesn't contain what you think it contains.  This sounds like a good opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Or perhaps you're some not inspecting the output correctly.  (How are you inspecting it?)

Comment: The dataF is the 2D array with the puzzle, I printed out txt file with that, definitely not its problem, I just need someone tell me how to print out 2D array in HTML.

Comment: If you're asking how to make a *table* in HTML, you'd start by taking a look at the `<table>` element and its subsequent child elements.  Again, there are tutorials for HTML readily available online.  If you have *specific* output and a *specific* question about why that output is occurring with a given set of input, we can help with that.  "Show me how to do HTML" is not a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not outputting any tags, just text. To output the contents in HTML you'll need to use HTML tags:

Outside your first loop:

```
bw.println("<table>");
```

Inside your first for loop:

```
bw.println("<tr>");
```

Inside your second for loop:

```
bw.println("<td>" + dataF(i,j) + "</td>");
```

After closing } for "j" loop:

```
bw.println("</tr>");
```

After closing } for "i" loop:

```
bw.println("</table>");
```

To make bold:

```
<strong>text</strong>
```

Comment: Thanks I think I just too new to HTML.